# Finding/replacing character entities with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have some markup that looks like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumb"><a href="http://domain.com/site/">Site</a> &raquo; 
<a href="http://domain.com/site/sub/"></a> &raquo; 
<a href="http://domain.com/site/sub/sub/">Heading</a> &raquo; Document title</div>
```

On the page, it looks like:

Site » » Heading » Document title

I'd like to use jQuery to look for the empty "a" tag, remove it, and then remove one of the >> characters.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#breadcrumb').length) {
        $('#breadcrumb a:empty').replaceWith('-');
        $('#breadcrumb').html($('#breadcrumb').html().replace(/» - »/, "»"));
    }
});
```

Notice that the >> characters are in the Javascript code itself. This works, but it doesn't seem right. I am looking for the proper way to find that character via regex. Or, I am looking for someone to say that this code is fine. :) I've tested it, and it seems to work in the browsers I've used. Thanks.

(I will eventually fix the process that creates these breadcrumbs, so that it no longer outputs the empty  tag... but I am looking for a stop-gap!)

Comment: It looks fine and if it works why change it? Is there a perceived time lag while it processes? How else would you have the << character than hard coded? What I'm trying to get at what doesn't look/feel right to you about it?

Comment: Thanks. It seems weird to have the literal >> character in there. Also, when I view the .js file in a web browser, it has funky characters around it. But, like I said it work. Perhaps it's an encoding issue with .js files served via apache.

Answer (score 2):

You're good, regex expressions in javascript are denoted using slashes in the same way that string are denoted by quotes. It's confusing when you first see it but this is a perfectly valid javascript regex expression.

Comment: Noting that in this case quotes for `"» - »"` instead of `/» - »/` would also work, since the regular expression isn't anything more than a literal string.

Comment: True. I've just found that it's good practice to always denote regex using slashes for simple clarity so I know what's in there is being processed as regex (to many other languages floating around my head where replace() uses strings instead of regex...)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery DOM manipulation API

next()

and

remove()

```
$('#breadcrumb a:empty').next().remove();
$('#breadcrumb a:empty').remove();
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, but it's not working for me. Specifically, next() removes the next <a href...>...</a> tag, not the &raquo;.